# Mysql join with sorting

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables say: user and library. The library contains books sorted in a 
certain way; a user can elect to sort his books in a certain way as well. The 
structure (and sample data) for the two tables will look thus:

### library

bookid  position
10             1
12             2
14             3
16             4

### user

userid  bookid  position 
12669       12         1
12669       10          2

I want a query to return all the books for user, 12669, sorted by position i.e:

**select bookid from user where userid = 12669 group by position**
After it has return these sorted books, it should return the other bookids (not present in user) that are in the library. No bookid should be repeated. The result of these scenario will look thus:

12
10
14
16

In other words: *All the books in library should be returned by this query but 
with the books selected by user sorted according to user.position*
I reckon I may need some kind of join statement for this. I tried: 
**select bookid from user u right join library l on u.bookid = l.bookid where u.userid = 12669 group by u.position** 
However, I get a syntax error for this. What is the best way to solve this 'problem'? Many thanks.

Comment: You should include the actual content of any error message in your post.  It makes it easier for us to diagnose your problem.  Help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick :)

```
SELECT l.bookid
FROM library l
LEFT OUTER JOIN user u on u.bookid = l.bookid
WHERE u.userid = 12669
ORDER BY isnull(u.position, 99999), l.position
```

Comment: Ummm, this completely ignores values in the USER.POSITION column and so will not return the desired output.

Comment: @APC indeed! I've added the `user.position` to fix the problem.

Comment: Also you're using an inner join, which means it only returns results for books in the USER table.  The need for an outer join was one of the few things the OP has got right in their original query :)

Comment: This won't work as required when the USER table has more than userid in it.  So, one more edit and you will have reproduced my solution exactly :)

Comment: Still not right.  Putting the userid in the where clause turns the outer join into an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your posted query includes in its projection a column name which doesn't belong to either of the tables involved.

Secondly, you are using GROUP BY where sorting is carried out by ORDER BY.

Third point: As @Romil points out, the reference to the USER table in the WHERE clause overrides the outer join, and effectively enforces an inner join.  So you need to select from an inline view on the USER table.

Finally, to get the sort order you want, you need to band all the USER.POSITIONs first.  This version of your query uses IFNULL to assign an extremely high value to any rows which don't have a joined USER record.  So it will sort by all the returned USER.POSITION values then by LIBRARY.POSITION for all the remaining books.

```
select l.bookid 
from ( select * from user
        where userid = 12669 ) u
   right join library l 
     on (u.bookid = l.bookid) 
order by ifnull(u.position, 999999999) , l.position
```

NB: if you are indexing [the Library of Babel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Library_of_Babel) and so might have enough shelves to support more than 999999999 positions just bump up that subsituted value.

---

> "This didn't work for me. It didn't return the bookids in the
>   arrangement I wanted. "

Frankly I find that surprising.  Here is [a SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d606e/2) which definitely returns your sample data in the order you specify.  So I repeat my earlier question: do your posted table descriptions match your actual tables *exactly* ?

Comment: In your sql, it will not return the bookid which are not in users list but available in library. The query posted by me do all the jobs as mentioned in question.

Comment: @Romil - good point.  I had focused on the ordering and missed the problem with the where clause.  And of course I hadn't tested it. But I have now!

Comment: This didn't work for me. It didn't return the bookids in the arrangement I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Other than the table & column names, the posted table descriptions match the actual tables exactly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT library.bookid bookid 
FROM   library 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                  FROM   [user] 
                  WHERE  [USER].userid = 12669) users 
         ON [USERs].bookid = library.bookid 
ORDER  BY [USERs].userid DESC, 
          [USERs].position, 
          library.position
```

Comment: I tried your solution, I'm getting the error: Unknown column 'library.bookid' in 'field list'

Comment: @user585566 - do your posted table descriptions match your actual tables *exactly* ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks APC, Romil and aF. I finally figured out a solution that didn't use a join.
This worked for me:

```
(
SELECT bookid
FROM user
WHERE userid = 12669
ORDER BY position
)
UNION (
SELECT bookid
FROM library
)
```

The first query selects the **ordered** bookids from user then the **union** statement selects *every other* book from library and adds this to the result set. The arrangement of this later group wasn't important.

Comment: This will not *guarantee* the result you want.  The docs say: "use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows ... If ORDER BY appears without LIMIT in a SELECT, it is optimized away because it will have no effect anyway."  Find out more: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html